# Show default form

Tags: c#, winforms

Before I used MDI and it worked fine, I could show my ListForm in MainForm. Now that I don't want to use MDI, it didn't work.

Before, with Mdi:

```
public partial class Le_MainForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Le_MainForm()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            this.Name = "MainUSER";

            if (Program.IsFA) barButtonItem_OrdList.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Never;

            Liste_Ordres f_Liste = new Liste_Ordres();
            f_Liste.MdiParent = this;
            f_Liste.Show();
        }




        private void barButtonItem_ListeOrdres_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Close_AllForm();
            Liste_Ordres f_Liste = new Liste_Ordres();
            f_Liste.MdiParent = this;
            f_Liste.Show();
        }

        private void barButtonItem_CreatOrdreAller_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Close_AllForm();
            Program.AllerRetour = "Ordre Aller";
            Fiche_Ordre f_Fiche = new Fiche_Ordre();
            f_Fiche.MdiParent = this;
            f_Fiche.Show();
        }
```

Now, after I eliminated the Mdi  `//this.IsMdiContainer = true;`

and all Forms inherited from MainForm:

```
public partial class Liste_Ordres : Le_MainForm
    {
    .....
```

I cannot show my ListeForm in MainFrom

```
public partial class Le_MainForm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
    {
        public Le_MainForm()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            this.Name = "MainUSER";

            if (Program.IsFA) barButtonItem_OrdList.Visibility = DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemVisibility.Never;

            Liste_Ordres f_Liste = new Liste_Ordres();
            // f_Liste.MdiParent = this;
            f_Liste.Show();
        }
```

Someone has any idea ?

Comment: It didn't appear the programme not the form

Comment: Why are your other forms inheriting from MainForm?

Comment: @Servy to avoid using Mdi, i m from ASP.NET. in my world ASP.NET there is a Master Page, but in world WinFrom there Master Page not exist. so i use Mdi for creating pseudo MasterPage. and then i got some advise it is better to avoid Mdi and use heritaed instead

Comment: MDI and inheritance are two VERY different concepts.  Do you want one mainform with several other forms inside of it, or do you want to create an abstract mainform that is never actually created but merely serves as a template for other forms?  The latter would use inheritance, and if so you would want to rename your `MainForm` to reflect that, i.e. `Template` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your MainForm to be something like a master page, you can use only the MainForm and design all other masks not as Forms but as Controls you put on that MainForm.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured a way to open an inheriting form on Initialization. 
First of all, in my MainForm I created an integer outside of any functions:

```
private int a = 1;
```

Then for my mainform I created a protected virtual on_Load event:

```
protected virtual void Le_MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (a == 1)
    {
        Liste_Ordres frm = new Liste_Ordres();
        frm.Show();
        a = 0;
    }
}
```

Next in my inheriting form, I overrided the on_Load event:

```
protected override void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

That at least got both forms open without using Mdi (though in a rather round about way), but now another problem remains:
When both forms open, MainForm opens in front of inheriting (no matter if you try using functions BringToFront() and SendToBack()).

Perhaps when I figure that problem out (If I do), then I will edit this answer, but for now this is the end.
Hope this works!